# Is there a way to avoid using 'call' in Coffeescript?

Tags: function, call, this, coffeescript

I'm writing a simple Twitter client to play with coffeescript. I have an object literal with some functions that call each other via callbacks.

```
somebject =
  foo: 'bar'
  authenticateAndGetTweets: ->
    console.log "Authorizing using oauth"
    oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage(this.oauthdetails)
    oauth.authorize( this.afterLogin.call this )
  afterLogin: ->
    this.getTweets(this.pollinterval)
```

<strike>This code works perfectly.</strike> **Edit:** actually this.afterlogin should be sent as a callback above, not ran immediately, as Trevor noted below.

If, within authenticateAndGetTweets, I removed the 'call' and just ran:

```
oauth.authorize( this.afterLogin )
```

and don't use 'call', I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getTweets
```

Which makes sense, since 'this' in afterLogin is bound to the thing that initiated the callback rather than 'someobject' my object literal.

I was wondering if there's some magic in Coffeescript I could be doing instead of 'call'. Initially I thought using the '=>' but the code will give the same error as above if '=>' is used.

So is there a way I can avoid using call? Or does coffeescript not obviate the need for it? What made '=>' not work how I expected it to?

Thanks. I'm really enjoying coffeescript so far and want to make sure I'm doing things 'the right way'.

Comment: I did, but didn't understand your code. `this.afterLogin.call this` calls it immediately (it's identical to `@afterLogin()`), where `this.afterLogin` retrieves the function. Are you sure you aren't looking for [`Function::bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Matyr I mentioned I was already using 'call' in the title of the question, so saying 'use call' wasn't really much of an answer. Your second question makes a good point though: I'm actually running a function rather than specifying a function to run as a callback (which is what I want to do). I'll check this out now.

Comment: Uh yes, I meant "_Why_ `.call`? _You mean_ `.bind`?" Sorry for confusing you further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As matyr points out in his comments, the line

```
oauth.authorize( this.afterLogin.call this )
```

doesn't cause `this.afterLogin` to be called as a callback by `oauth.authorize`; instead, it's equivalent to

```
oauth.authorize this.afterLogin()
```

Assuming that you want `this.afterLogin` to used as a callback by `oauth.authorize`, megakorre's answer gives a correct CoffeeScript idiom. An alternative approach supported by many modern JS environments, as matyr points out, would be to write

```
oauth.authorize( this.afterLogin.bind this )
```

There's no CoffeeScript shorthand for this, partly because `Function::bind` isn't supported by all major browsers. You could also use the `bind` function from a library like [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/):

```
oauth.authorize( _.bind this.afterLogin, this )
```

Finally, if you were to define `someobject` as a class instead, you could use `=>` to define `afterLogin` such that it's always bound to the instance, e.g.

```
class SomeClass
  foo: 'bar'
  authenticateAndGetTweets: ->
    console.log "Authorizing using oauth"
    oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage(this.oauthdetails)
    oauth.authorize(this.afterLogin)
  afterLogin: =>
    this.getTweets(this.pollinterval)

someobject = new SomeClass
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your comprehensive answer: I do actually want this.afterLogin to be run as a callback, with 'this' set to the object the afterlogin is part of.

Comment: Cool, see expanded answer for a couple more ideas.

Comment: Thanks again Trevor: using an object literal vs using a class also answers my second question re: why => wasn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

you can put a lambda in the function call like so

```
auth.authorize(=> @afterLogin())
```

Comment: Thanks, wrapping in a lambda works too - upboat! However in this case I always want the function to be called with this as the object it's a property of, so @Trevor's suggestion of using a class and => is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either the call or apply methods because they set the scope of the function (the value of this). The error results because the default scope is the `window` object.